# Get Quotas Openstack API

Tags: openstack

I'm referring to use Openstack API to get quota usage from Openstack Cloud. I did exactly as document at https://developer.openstack.org/api-ref/compute/.

But It didn't work, with api:

```
<host>/v2/{tenant_id}/os-quota-sets/{tenant_id}/detail
```

or

```
<host>/v2/{tenant_id}/os-quota-sets/detail
```

It worked with api:

```
<host>/v2/{tenant_id}/os-quota-sets/{tenant_id}
```

But, I want to get details. Did I do anything wrong?

Comment: what error message did you get? I have`Policy doesn't allow os_compute_api:os-quota-sets:detail to be performed.` If it is the same, you need to modify your nova policy file.

Answer (score 0):

OpenStack client can be used... And you can use command line tools.... Below is the link which can help you.
https://docs.openstack.org/nova/pike/admin/quotas.html

You can install OpenStack SDK, you can go through API documentation section for networking.

Below is the link:

https://docs.openstack.org/openstacksdk/latest/user/proxies/network.html#openstack.network.v2._proxy.Proxy.update_quota

You may find methods like:

```
delete_quota(quota, ignore_missing=True)
get_quota(quota, details=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

API for getting project quota can be called as,

```
requests.get('http://'+url+':8774/v2.1/os-quota-sets/'+projectid+'/detail',headers={'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Auth-Token': token})
```

You will have to pass your project id in path and 'X-Auth-Token' parameter in headers which can be extracted as,

```
url = [Your Cloud Machine IP Goes here]

def gettokenForUser(username,password):

    payload1 = {
    "auth": {
        "identity": {
            "methods": [
                "password"
            ],
            "password": {
                "user": {
                    "name": username,
                    "domain": {
                        "name": "Default"
                    },
                    "password": password
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    response = requests.post('http://'+url+':5000/v3/auth/tokens',
                    headers={'content-type': 'application/json'},
                    data=json.dumps(payload1))

    return response.headers['X-Subject-Token']
```